# overlap lable customise in tablecell iOS

Tags: ios

I have 3 section in table, so I want to assign value for my title cell in section 1 (row 2 and 3) only, so that title is appear in next section and jump up in every cell. help me solve that!
here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //------------ Customise lable and image in cell ----------------------
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        self.nameModuleLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 5, 80, 30)];
        self.nameModuleLable.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
        self.nameModuleLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.nameModuleLable.tag = 1;

        self.nuberOfMessLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 40, 40)];
        self.nuberOfMessLable.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
        self.nuberOfMessLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.nuberOfMessLable.tag = 2;

        self.cellimageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.cellimageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 11, 20, 20);
        self.cellimageView.tag = 3;

        [cell addSubview:self.nameModuleLable];
        [cell addSubview:self.cellimageView];
        [cell addSubview:self.nuberOfMessLable];

    }
    self.nameModuleLable = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    self.nuberOfMessLable = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    self.cellimageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    // -------------Number of section in cell 2 and 3 in section 0-----------
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            if (!numberOfMessage) {
                self.nuberOfMessLable.text = @"0";
            } else {
                self.nuberOfMessLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberOfMessage];
            }
        }

        else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            if (!numberOfFriend) {
                self.nuberOfMessLable.text = @"0";
            } else {
                self.nuberOfMessLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberOfFriend];
            }
        }
        //-------------------Assign value for home's menu------------------------------
        self.nameModuleLable.text = [home objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.cellimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[homeImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        //--------------------------Assign value for application's menu--------------------------
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        Module *currentModule = [self.moduleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.nameModuleLable.text = [currentModule valueForKey:@"mName"];
        NSString *avaImageString = [currentModule valueForKey:@"mImage"];
        NSURL *urlAva = [NSURL URLWithString:avaImageString];
        NSData *dataAva = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAva];
        self.cellimageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataAva];
        //---------------------------Logout section---------------------------------
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        self.nameModuleLable.text = [logout objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.cellimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoutImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's spelled "LABEL" :)

Comment: please elaborate what u wanna do and what's the meaning of "so that title is appear in next section and jump up in every cell" this .. ?

Comment: Sorry about my level of english ^^! My question, I assign numberOfMessLable.text value in section 0 only, but it appear in section 1 also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some advices:

1. Creat a custom subClass(such as named: CustomCell) of UITableViewCell,which contain nameModuleLable nuberOfMessLable and cellimageView. Initialization the three subViews above at CustomCell's init method.
2. Change the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

   ```
       -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil)
       {
           //------------ Customise lable and image in cell ----------------------
           cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


       }


       // -------------Number of section in cell 2 and 3 in section 0-----------
       if (indexPath.section == 0) {
           if (indexPath.row == 2) {
               if (!numberOfMessage) {
                   cell.nuberOfMessLable.text = @"0";
               } else {
                   cell.nuberOfMessLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberOfMessage];
               }
           }

           else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
               if (!numberOfFriend) {
                   cell.nuberOfMessLable.text = @"0";
               } else {
                   cell.nuberOfMessLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberOfFriend];
               }
           }
           //-------------------Assign value for home's menu------------------------------
           cell.nameModuleLable.text = [home objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.cellimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[homeImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
           //--------------------------Assign value for application's menu--------------------------
       } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
           Module *currentModule = [self.moduleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.nameModuleLable.text = [currentModule valueForKey:@"mName"];
           NSString *avaImageString = [currentModule valueForKey:@"mImage"];
           NSURL *urlAva = [NSURL URLWithString:avaImageString];
           NSData *dataAva = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAva];
           cell.cellimageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataAva];
           //---------------------------Logout section---------------------------------
       } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
           cell.nameModuleLable.text = [logout objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.cellimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoutImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       }

       return cell;
   }
   ```
3. In order to assign value for your title cell ,alse creat some NSString at ViewController to hold the title value.

Comment: Change all lable to label :]

Comment: Every cell have their own subViews is the most traditional way. you can have a look at the apple's sample code: [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) [CurrentAddress](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html)